# Show that for all positive integers n, $\text{hcf}(6n + 8, 2n + 3) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

To show that for all positive integers $n$, $\operatorname{hcf}(6n + 8, 2n + 3) = 1$

Can I just show that since n is a positive integer, so $6n + 8 > 4n + 5$.

When we apply long division

$6n + 8 = 1(4n + 5) + (2n +3)$

$4n + 5 = 1(2n + 3) + (2n +2)$

$2n + 3 = 1(2n + 2) + 1$

Therefore the highest common factor of $6n+8$ and $4n+5$ is $1.$

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Side note: $\gcd$ (`\gcd`) is the standard name for "hcf".

Comment: Note: In India and the Southeast countries, HCF is preferred to GCD... maybe that's why OP used it..

Comment: You can also note that any common factor divides $3(2n+3)-(6n+8)=1$.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159468/if-n-is-an-integer-then-gcd2n3-3n-2-1-text-or/1159509#1159509) for a general method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is simple and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you've done; it's correct. Another way, but somewhat informal/intuitive...

$$6n + 8 = 2(3n+4)=6(n+1)+2=2(3(n+1)+1) => Even$$
$$2n + 3 = 2(n+1) + 1 => Odd$$

Now, it's not necessary that gcd(a,b) = 1 when a,b are odd and even respectively, but since they don't have a common factor after factorizing out, they're coprime.

Your proof is rigorous, so it's fine really.