# Prove that the gcd of ( 8n+19 , 3n+7 ) =1

Tags: induction, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I want to show that the gcd of $( 8n+19 , 3n+7 ) =1$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I would like to prove this through mathematical induction and generalize it for the set of all integers.

Base Case: $n=1$

$$gcd(8+19,3+7) = gcd(27,10) = 1 $$

Assume $n = k$ holds.

WTS it is also true for $n=k+1$.
$$gcd(8k+27,3k+10)=1$$

I am stuck here, please let advise me on how to continue from here. Also I am not sure if mathematical induction is the right approach. If a more elegant approach exists, please let me know.

Comment: Do you know that $gcd(a,b) = gcd(a-b,b)$? I don't think you need to do math induction for this question

Comment: I don't think induction is the way to go. $3(8n+19)-8(3n+7)$ is probly a better idea.

Comment: Yes, but here we have $gcd(a+8,b+3)$, correct?

Comment: Oh, I think that is better

Comment: Use $\,3(19)-7(8) = 1\,$ in the dupe to conclude the gcd $ = \gcd(n,1) = 1\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is suffices to find $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
(8n+19)x+(3n+7)y=1
$$
that is $n(8x+3y)+(19x+7y)=1$. In order to do so, let us find $x,y$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
8x+3y=0\\
19x+7y=1
\end{cases}
$$
And the solution of the last system is $x=3$, $y=-8$.

Comment: Oh this makes sense, thanks so much!

Comment: @Alice Said more conceptually: *eliminate* $\,n,\,$ as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1245530/242).

Answer (score 0):

Another approch would be consider the polynomials of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$,
\begin{align}
f(x)&=8x+19,\\g(x)&=3x+7.
\end{align}
Divide $f(x)$ by $g(x)$, you get
$$
f(x)=\frac{8}{3}g(x)+\frac{1}{3}
$$
and then
$$
1=3f(x)-8g(x).
$$
In particular, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$,
$$
1=3f(n)-8g(n).
$$
This is a Bézout identity which tells you that gcd$(f(n),g(n))=1$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which is what you want to prove.