# Show that $\gcd(5a+8, 7a+3)=1\textrm{ or } 41$. Best way to solve a problem of this sort?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Let $a\in \mathbb Z$. Show that $\gcd(5a+8, 7a+3)=1\textrm{ or } 41$.
Knowing that $\forall k \in\mathbb Z, \gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b, a-kb)$.

I actually know how to solve this particular problem: $\gcd(5a+8, 7a+3)=\gcd(5a+8,2a-5)=\gcd(a+18,2a-5)=\gcd(a+18:-41)$. So $(a+8:-41)\in \{1, 41\}$.

What I want to know is if there's an efficient way to solve any problem of this sort. The goal being to eliminate variables from either side of the gcd no matter the parity of the terms involved. Manually adding and substracting to each sum to have the variable $a$ cancelled.
This is only the simplest example. Another one is: $\gcd(2a^2+3a-1, 5a+6)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're just going through the Euclidean algorithm except with expressions instead of integers.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1911456/589

Comment: The standard methods are all described in the linked dupes (and their links).

Answer (score 0):

Say there is $d$ which divide both. Then $d\mid 7(5a+8)$ and $d\mid 5(7a+3)$ so $d$ divide their difference: $$d\mid 7(5a+8)-5(7a+3) = 41$$

So $d\in\{1,41\}$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: But my ansewr is totally of different kind. @BillDubuque

Comment: Not true.  It is the *exactly* the same as the first method in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1245530/242) in the first linked dupe (and is presented here *many* times, as anyone experienced in ENT here would surely know). Be sure to read the linked page on recent site policy changes which pertains to matters like this.

Comment: How on earth could I find that post of yours from 6 years ago? @BillDubuque