# Prove that if $d$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$ then $d$ is a divisor of $2020$, I think the book is wrong

Tags: divisibility

$a = 113n + 10$

$b = 89n - 10$

$n$ is a natural number

**Question:** Prove that if $d$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$ then $d$ is a divisor of $2020$

**The book's solution:**

$d / a$

$d / b$

then $d / a + b$ so $d / 202n$

$d / 10(202n)$

$d / 2020n$

so $d / 2020$

But here is my problem with this solution.

$d / 2020n$ shouldn't mean $d / 2020$ because we don't know if $n$ is co-prime with $d$ or not.

If $n$ was co-prime then yes $d / 2020$ but we don't know that so I think the solution is wrong.

What do you think? Is the book correct and am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have a link to the book solution? This looks more like a student's solution.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1245530/242) in the linked dupe for the standard methods to solve such problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes $d | 2020 n$ doesn't mean that $d | 2020$.
May be in the book they want to say :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
d & | & a \\
d & | & b
\end{array}\right.$$
then :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
d & | & 113 n + 10 \\
d & | & 89 n - 10
\end{array}\right.$$
then :
$$d | 89 (113 n + 10) - 113 (89 n - 10) = 2020$$

Comment: Consider using `\mid` instead of `|` to avoid spacing issues

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).