# If $(k,l) = 1$, show that $(b_2k-b_1l, a_1l-a_2k) = 1$ for $a_1b_2-a_2b_1=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

**Problem:**

> If $(k,l) = 1$, show that $(b_2k-b_1l, a_1l-a_2k) = 1$ for $a_1b_2-a_2b_1=1$
>   Note: ($a_1, a_2,b_1,b_2,k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$)

Also note that the actual (bigger) problem is:

> If $m = a_1x+b_1y$ (*Eq1*) and $n=a_2x+b_2y$ (*Eq2*) and $a_1b_2-a_2b_1=1$, prove that $(m,n)=(x,y)$.

I have proved that $(m,n) = d | x \text{ and } d|y$ I am left to prove that $d = (x,y)$, that's why I asked above question.

I had made $m = dk$ and $n = dl$ ($\therefore (k,l)=1$) and after substitution in *Eq1* and *Eq2* for $x$ and $y$ values I got $d(b_2k-b_1l)=x$ and $d(a_1l-a_2k) = y$. If I can show  $(b_2k-b_1l, a_1l-a_2k) = 1$ then definitely $d = (x,y)$

**Method:**

Suppose $(b_2k-b_1l, a_1l-a_2k) = d > 1$. Then, $d | b_2k, d | b_1l, d|a_1l,d|a_2k$ must be true.

This implies $d|a_2b_1kl$ and $d|a_1b_2kl$ must be true. Let, $dp = a_2b_1kl \implies a_2b_1 = \frac{dp}{kl}$ and $dq=a_1b_2kl\implies a_1b_2 = \frac{dq}{kl}$

So, $$a_1b_2-a_2b_1=1 \implies \frac{d(q-p)}{kl}=1 \implies kl =d(q-p)$$

I am stuck here. How to prove a contradiction so that $d = 1$?

Comment: Is it $a_1b_2-a_2b_2=1$ OR $a_1b_2-a_2b_1=1$? You have written the first one but applied the second in your working?

Comment: @Aniket Thanks fixed it! Just too tired of so much of latex subscripting! :P

Comment: Immediate consequence of the [theorem here,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1159509/242) since the determinant of the linear map $= 1.\ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd statement in this paragraph is wrong.

> Suppose $(b_2k-b_1l, a_1l-a_2k) = d > 1$. Then, $d | b_2k, d | b_1l, d|a_1l,d|a_2k$ must be true.

Rather it should be as follows: 
$d|b_2k-b_1l$ and $d|a_1l-a_2k$. 
Now, $$d|b_2k-b_1l \Rightarrow d|a_1b_2k-a_1b_1l$$ and 
$$d|a_1l-a_2k \Rightarrow d|a_1b_1l-a_2b_1k$$

Hence $d|(a_1b_2k-a_1b_1l)+(a_1b_1l-a_2b_1k) \Rightarrow d|(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)k \Rightarrow d|k$ 
Similarly, you can show that $d|l$. 
So $d|k$ and $d|l$ . 
 
But by assumption $(k,l)=1$ 
Hence contradiction $\Rightarrow d=1$ .

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks! I knew that $d|a-b$ does not imply $d|a$ but somehow forgot to remember it during solving this problem. your rest part of the solution is super awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If you learned a bit about determinants, the equation involving $a_1b_2-a_2b_1$ might remind you of them. So let us try whether linear algebra might be useful here.

Knowing that $(k,l)=1$ means that there exist some integers $u$ and $v$ such that $uk+vl=1$.

We also know that $a_1b_2-a_2b_1=1$.

This means that these [determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) are both equal to one:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_1 & a_2 \\
  b_1 & b_2
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
  l & u \\
 -k & v
\end{vmatrix}=1
$$

Since we know that determinant of [product of two matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) is [product of determinants](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product)

The product is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  a_1 & a_2 \\
  b_1 & b_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  l & u \\
 -k & v
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_1l-a_2k & x \\
  b_1l-b_2k & y 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $x,y\in\mathbb Z$. (Namely $x=a_1u+a_2v$, $y=b_1u+b_2v$.)

If we expand the last determinant, we get
$$x(b_1l-b_2k)+y(a_1l-a_2k)=1$$
which means that $(b_1l-b_2k)$ and $(a_1l-a_2k)$ are coprime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer is definitely useful, however, I do not know determinants :( Perhaps, when I learn them, I will come back and have a look at this :)